# Spring - how to load configuration from database?

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, configuration

I need to load configuration settings used in applicationContext.xml from relational database (PostgreSQL).

I followed this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28893/Loading-Application-Properties-from-a-Database but it uses a deprecated "Spring Modules" jar file.

Is there some another technique how to achieve it? I use Spring 3.

My idea is to set only access setting to database (hostname, dbname, username, password) for creating a datasource and probably create some own handler class(?) for loading setting from DB. In applicationContext.xml I will use settings in the same way - ${foo.bar}.

Plesase share your experience and code examples with this topic and Spring 3.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's no longer bundled in Spring 3 I don't see any reason why you can't use it. Just include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-modules-jakarta-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

On your maven pom alongside with other Spring 3 dependencies and the setup as described in the tutorial should look alright.

If that produces specific error please post the details (incl. stack trace) so we can help investigate further